# sed and double quotes

Tags: sed, escaping, double-quotes

I have a problem with a script, if the file test.cfg doesn't exist then the correct Password will be written in the file test.cfg, but if the test.cfg exists then the Password won't get changed.

Here is my script test.sh -password mysecret

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while test $# -gt 0; do
    case "$1" in
        "-password" )
        password="$2"
        shift
    ;;
    esac
shift
done

grep "password = " test.cfg &>/dev/null
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then # Vorhanden!
    sed -i test.cfg -e "s/^\(password = \).\"*$/\1${password}\";/"
else # Nicht vorhanden!
    echo "password = \"${password}\";" >> test.cfg
fi
```

When the test.cfg does not exist it will be created with Content

```
password = "mysecret";
```

but now the line exists, then the password won't get changed to test.sh -password mynewsecret

It's only get changed to:

```
password = mynewsecret;
```

Comment: I trust you aren't actually storing passwords in clear text, or (if you are) then you don't consider security very important — the passwords are merely casual protection against misuse.

Comment: This password is only for protecting a gameserver,  the interface i'm using is not very compatible for games, else hlds,srcds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\"*` means *double quote zero or more times. You need a bit different regular expression:

```bsh
sed -e "s/^\(password = \)\".*\"$/\1\"$password\";/"
```

Note that `case` is suitable if there is more then one possibility, here `if` would be more suitable:

```bsh
while (( $# )) ; do
    if [[ $1 == '-password' ]] ; then
        password=$2
        shift
    fi
    shift    # What does this do, anyway?
done

if grep -q 'password = ' test.cfg ; then
    sed -i~ -e "s/^\(password = \)\".*\"$/\1\"$password\";/" test.cfg
else
    echo 'password = "'"$password"'";' >> test.cfg
fi
```

Comment: Thank you too, it works, the second shift is in the code, because i copy/paste only the part where i have problems, this script is for gameservers managed by tekbase, so my friends can start,stop the server, so that they don't need ssh access to my server, my coding skill is verry low, allmost every thing i need i can found online, but such things like these scripts i didn't find so i tried it by my self. Sorry for my bad english (; from germany

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your replacement string doesn't include the double quotes that you remove, and your code doesn't match what you expect either.  Use this — it moves the first `\"` to the correct place.

```
sed -i -e "s/^\(password = \).*$/\1\"${password}\";/" test.cfg
```

As an aside, you must be using GNU `sed`. Mac OS X `sed` complains `sed: -i may not be used with stdin` because it expects an argument to `-i`, so it treats `test.cfg` as the suffix to be added to the backup file (and therefore there is no file name argument, so it is reading from standard input).  I still think it is best to put option arguments before non-option arguments, even though GNU `getopt(1)` (or `getopt_long(1)`) supports interleaving option and non-option arguments.  I've reordered the command line appropriately.  It still won't work on Mac OS X; the suffix is not optional with the `-i` there.